# Add different controls dynamically to each row of sap.ui.table.TreeTable

Tags: sapui5

I'm working with SAPUI5. I have a `sap.ui.table.TreeTable` in XML and I want to load data from a JSONModel dynamically into the rows.

In the first row, I want to show `Text`, in the second, a `BulletMicroChart`.

How can I realize it?

```xml
<t:TreeTable id="treeTable"
  rows="{
    path: 'nodeModel>/nodeRoot',
    parameters: {
      arrayNames: [
        'children'
      ]
    }
  }"
  enableSelectAll="false"
  expandFirstLevel="true"
  selectionMode="Single"
  enableColumnReordering="false"
>
  <t:columns>
    <t:Column>
      <t:template>
        <Text text="{nodeModel>id}" />
      </t:template>
    </t:Column>
    <t:Column label="Test">
      <t:template>
        <Text text="{nodeModel>prs1}" />
      </t:template>
    </t:Column>
  </t:columns>
</t:TreeTable>
```

How can I add now in the second row a Bullet Micro Chart in order to visualize the numbers?

I need to add this in the second row dynamically:

```xml
<microchart:BulletMicroChart
  scale="M"
  targetValue="100"
  forecastValue="110"
  size="Responsive"
>
  <microchart:actual>
    <microchart:BulletMicroChartData value="120" color="Good" />
  </microchart:actual>
  <microchart:thresholds>
    <microchart:BulletMicroChartData value="0" color="Error" />
    <microchart:BulletMicroChartData value="50" color="Critical" />
    <microchart:BulletMicroChartData value="150" color="Critical" />
    <microchart:BulletMicroChartData value="200" color="Error" />
  </microchart:thresholds>
</microchart:BulletMicroChart>
```

#### Example:

> Name | Name1  Name2  Name3
>   Chart | Chart1 Chart2 Chart3

I can only show different data in each column not in each row.